# dynamic_cast of a reference to copied object fails

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have a function `getA()` which returns a const reference of `base` type `A`, since it's const, it cannot `dynamic_cast` it, so I make a copy of the const reference and then created a reference to the copied object, but when I call `dynamic_cast` to the reference of the copied object, it fails, the code is shown below:

```
struct A {
  int c = -1;
  virtual ~A() {}
};

struct B : A {int aa = 0;};

const A& getA(){
  std::unique_ptr<A> ap(new B);
  return *ap;
}


int main()
{
  const A& a = getA();
  A acopy = a;
  acopy.c = -2;
  A& acopyr = acopy;
  std::cout << a.c << std::endl;
  try{
    B& b = dynamic_cast<B&>(acopyr);
    std::cout << b.aa << std::endl;
  }catch(std::bad_cast b){
    std::cout << "bad" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The output is

```
-1
bad
```

Comment: Isn't `dynamic_cast<B const &>(a)` all you need ? Edit : also, `getA()` returns a dangling reference since `ap` destroys its pointee at the closing brace.

Comment: Why do you think `acopy` is a `B`?  You make it an `A` with `A acopy = a;`.

Comment: @NathanOliver but `a` is `B`,  isn't?

Comment: @user3828398 `a` is but you declare `acopy` as an `A`.  If `acopy` is an `A` then it is no longer a `B`.

Answer (score 2):

`acopy` is an object of dynamic (and static) type `A`. Notice how it was declared: an object of type `A`. So of course it cannot be cast to a `B&`.

From your description, I take it you just want to dynamically cast `getA()` to a `const` reference to `B`. There's nothing stopping you from that:

```
 const B& b = dynamic_cast<const B&>(getA());
```

---

Side note: I assume the `getA` implementation in your question is just for demonstration purposes, but it's *very* wrong. As soon as `ap` goes out of scope (that is, as soon as `getA` returns), it will destroy the object to which it points, so you're returning a dangling reference and thus invoking Undefined Behaviour.